# $result = mysql_query($strSQL); not working

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have a page template (WordPress) that consists of a query, and display the output from the query.  It has stopped working.  The query does work when in phpMyAdmin.

`$strSQL = "SELECT xgqq_cimy_uef_data.ID, xgqq_cimy_uef_data.USER_ID, xgqq_cimy_uef_data.FIELD_ID AS UserID, xgqq_cimy_uef_data.VALUE AS Phone, xgqq_usermeta.user_id AS TheID, xgqq_usermeta.meta_key, xgqq_usermeta.meta_value AS FirstNameField, xgqq_usermeta_1.umeta_id AS LastNameID, xgqq_usermeta_1.meta_key, xgqq_usermeta_1.meta_value AS LastNameField, xgqq_users.user_email
FROM ((xgqq_cimy_uef_data INNER JOIN xgqq_users ON xgqq_cimy_uef_data.USER_ID = xgqq_users.ID) INNER JOIN xgqq_usermeta ON xgqq_users.ID = xgqq_usermeta.user_id) INNER JOIN xgqq_usermeta AS xgqq_usermeta_1 ON xgqq_usermeta.user_id = xgqq_usermeta_1.user_id
WHERE (((xgqq_cimy_uef_data.USER_ID)<>1) AND ((xgqq_cimy_uef_data.FIELD_ID)=4) AND ((xgqq_usermeta.meta_key)='first_name') AND ((xgqq_usermeta_1.meta_key)='last_name')) ORDER BY xgqq_usermeta_1.meta_value";`

```
   $result = mysql_query($strSQL);

      while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {

         $firstname = $row['FirstNameField'];
         $lastname = $row['LastNameField'];
         $email = $row['user_email'];
         $phone = $row['Phone'];
         $profile = $row['USER_ID'];

         //Outputs results into a table
         echo'   <tr>
                    <td>' . $firstname .' ' . $lastname .'</td>
                    <td><a href="mailto:' . $email.'">' . $email.'</a></td>
                    <td>' . $phone .'</td>
                    <td><a href="?profile_id='. $profile .'">View Profile</a></td>
               </tr>';
      }
```

When I turn error reporting on it points to

```
$result = mysql_query($strSQL);
```

as being the problem.  I am not quite sure what to change, despite trying suggestions here, and elsewhere, but it doesn't work.

Comment: What version of php are you using? Mysql is gone as of php 7.

Comment: Will be little clear if you put the php error in your question.

Comment: Remove these brackets (xgqq_cimy_uef_data.USER_ID) no need also from other columns

Comment: And as chris metioned if php version is 7 than u cant use mysql extension and also read the pgk comments about the specific error add in question

Comment: I think its version issue if query run properly in phpmyadmin

Comment: have you tried on other mysql tool? try add `var_dump(mysql_fetch_assoc($result));` under `$result = mysql_query($strSQL);` and show to our what the output or change `mysql_fetch_assoc` to `mysql_fetch_array`.

Comment: php version is 5.6.17

Comment: You might want to share the error message you get, so that we don't have to play the guessing game.

Comment: I've tried Baron's suggestions and they unfortunately didn't work.

The following are the error messages being reported:

` Deprecated: mysql_query(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead in /home8/lvismemb/public_html/wp-content/themes/BuilderChild-Foundation-Blank/ORIGmembers.php on line 74

Comment: More:
`Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home8/lvismemb/public_html/wp-content/themes/BuilderChild-Foundation-Blank/ORIGmembers.php on line 74

Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home8/lvismemb/public_html/wp-content/themes/BuilderChild-Foundation-Blank/ORIGmembers.php on line 74

`

Comment: Last error:  Warning: mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /home8/lvismemb/public_html/wp-content/themes/BuilderChild-Foundation-Blank/ORIGmembers.php on line 76

Comment: Line 76 is: `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {`

Comment: I found out what the problem was.  Someone had added the following to the .htaccess file.

AddHandler application/x-httpd-phpbetas .php

It's been commented out now.  Too many people working on a site is NOT a good thing.

Comment: It's the first error that caused you problems, all other errors were caused by that first one. Good on you for solving it! Next time, please include all relevant errors in the question :-) Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

your query should work, if it is not working, the only reason i can guess is that you are using latest version of php, and Mysql is depreciated in latest versions of php.

Comment: This is really more of a comment than an answer. And not only is it deprecated in the latest versions (since PHP 5.5), it was removed entirely in PHP 7.

Comment: Mysql is not deprecated ... mysql_* extension is deprecated and close in php7